# Cloud Run PubSub high latency

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I'm building a microservice application consisting of many microservices build with Node.js and running on Cloud Run. I use PubSub in several different ways:

1. For streaming data daily. The microservices responsible for gathering analytical data from different advertising services (Facebook Ads, LinkedIn Ads, etc.) use PubSub to stream data to a microservice responsible for uploading data to Google BigQuery. There also are services that stream a higher load of data (> 1 Gb) from CRMs and other services by splitting it into smaller chunks.
2. For messaging among microservices about different events that don't require an immediate response.

Earlier, I experienced some insignificant latency with PubSub. I know it's [an open issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/925) considering up to several seconds latency with low messages throughput. But in my case, we are talking about several minutes latency.

Also, I occasionally get an error message

> Received error while publishing: Total timeout of API google.pubsub.v1.Publisher exceeded 60000 milliseconds before any response was received.

I this case a message is not sent at all or is highly delayed.

This is how my code looks like.

```
const subscriptions = new Map<string, Subscription>();
const topics = new Map<string, Topic>();

const listenForMessages = async (
  subscriptionName: string,
  func: ListenerCallback,
  secInit = 300,
  secInter = 300
) => {
  let logger = new TestLogger("LISTEN_FOR_MSG");
  let init = true;
  const _setTimeout = () => {
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Subscription to ${subscriptionName} cancelled`);
      subscription.removeListener("message", messageHandler);
    }, (init ? secInit : secInter) * 1000);
    init = false;
    return timer;
  };

  const messageHandler = async (msg: Message) => {
    msg.ack();
    await func(JSON.parse(msg.data.toString()));
    // wait for next message
    timeout = _setTimeout();
  };

  let subscription: Subscription;

  if (subscriptions.has(subscriptionName)) {
    subscription = subscriptions.get(subscriptionName);
  } else {
    subscription = pubSubClient.subscription(subscriptionName);
    subscriptions.set(subscriptionName, subscription);
  }

  let timeout = _setTimeout();

  subscription.on("message", messageHandler);
  console.log(`Listening for messages: ${subscriptionName}`);
};

const publishMessage = async (
  data: WithAnyProps,
  topicName: string,
  options?: PubOpt
) => {
  const serializedData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(serializedData);
  try {
    let topic: Topic;
    if (topics.has(topicName)) {
      topic = topics.get(topicName);
    } else {
      topic = pubSubClient.topic(topicName, {
        batching: {
          maxMessages: options?.batchingMaxMessages,
          maxMilliseconds: options?.batchingMaxMilliseconds,
        },
      });
      topics.set(topicName, topic);
    }
    let msg = {
      data: dataBuffer,
      attributes: options.attributes,
    };

    await topic.publishMessage(msg);
    console.log(`Publishing to ${topicName}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Received error while publishing: ${err.message}`);
  }
};
```

A *listenerForMessage* function is triggered by an HTTP request.

**What I have already checked**

1. PubSub client is created only once outside the function.
2. Topics and Subscriptions are reused.
3. I made at least one instance of each container running to eliminate the possibility of delays triggered by cold start.
4. I tried to increase the CPU and Memory capacity of containers.
5. *batchingMaxMessages* and *batchingMaxMilliseconds* are set to 1
6. I checked that the latest version of @google-cloud/pubsub is installed.

**Notes**

1. High latency problem **occurs only in the cloud environment**. With local tests, everything works well.
2. Timeout error sometimes occurs in both environments.

Comment: Can you share how you run your code? Your webserver and the overall logic.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I'm not sure I got your question exactly, but I'll try to provide you with relevant information.  
All the code is running in Node.js on fully managed Cloud Run containers. 

I have a service, let's call it PipelineService, containing information about existing data pipelines: source and destination types, connection ids, the status of the pipeline (active/paused), last data transfer date, etc. I also have multiple services, let's say FacebookService, etc., containing holding information about source connection, access tokens, etc.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, There are also a GBQService holding google access tokens and addresses of destination tables. 

Once a day a Cloud Scheduler invokes a PipelineService. In turn, PipelineService wakes up source and destination services and activates a PubSub listener. They start to perform some warm-up operations and to listen for PubSub messages containing instructions about the time frame and addresses of data to retrieve. After the data is retrieved, it's sent via messages to  GBQService, which in turn uploads data to Google BigQuery.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, if at any given point the process fails and can't be automatically recovered, the message about the failure reason is sent back to the PipelineService and saved into the database. Otherwise, success confirmation is sent.  Each service removes a listener after a certain time without new messages and shuts down.

Comment: Ok, excuse my lack of precision: I would like to know what is the piece of code that invoke the message publish part. With Cloud Run you must have a webserver. An endpoint should be invoked on it, and, in that endpoint, your publish function call. I would like to understand that chain of call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my understanding of Cloud Run Container's lifecycle. I used to send HTTP response 202 while having PubSub working in the background. After sending the response, the container switched to the idling state, what looked like high latency in my logs.